# Is Kermit the only muppet to appear in both the Sesame Street and Muppets franchises?

Tags: muppets, sesame-street

Kermit the Frog is notable for appearing in both Sesame Street (often via the [Sesame Street News Flash](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Sesame_Street_News_Flash) skits) and the Muppets franchise, but I can't recall it ever happening with any other character. According to [the Wikipedia article on the 2011 film *The Muppets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Muppets_(film)):

> A cameo was written for the Sesame Street Muppet Elmo, but was rejected by Disney's attorneys and representatives from Sesame Workshop.

Have any other muppets actually appeared on both media? Or is Kermit the only one?

I'm just interested in officially produced, live-action media, and not things like interviews or documentaries.

Comment: When did Kermit the Frog appear on Sesame Street?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - Lots. Probably the most famous is [Its not Easy Being Green](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv-P7ny5DVAhUCQSYKHRFSAp8QyCkIJTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D51BQfPeSK8k&usg=AFQjCNFcW_ybo6QrE2_oDpgid5joYuUm3g), but I remember him in several one-on-ones with kids too, and quite a few skits as a reporter.

Comment: @T.E.D. An example of Kermit making a cameo should be added into the original question.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Added an example

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**No.** Among the more notable examples, Big Bird, Ernie and Bert, Oscar the Grouch and the blue Beautiful Day Monster ([this guy](https://muppetmindset.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/beautiful-day-monster.png)) had appeard in both franchises. You can see a more detailed account from [Wikia](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Crossovers) after this video of Big Bird singing a song on the Muppet Show:

> - Several Muppet characters from previous productions, including Beautiful Day Monster, Scudge and Fred's son, appeared during the first season of Sesame Street.
> - Ernie and Bert make a cameo appearance in the Muppet Show pilot The Muppets Valentine Show, while Bert appears in the pilot The Muppet Show: Sex and Violence.
> - Ernie and Bert appear in episode 102 of The Muppet Show. Bert danced with guest star Connie Stevens.
> - Big Bird makes a guest appearance in episode 318 of The Muppet Show, performing a song with guest star Leslie Uggams and fending off the romantic advances of Gonzo.
> - Numerous Sesame Street characters appear in Episode 518 of The Muppet Show.
> - Big Bird has a cameo appearance in The Muppet Movie; also, several dozens of Sesame Street characters appear in the film's closing shot.
> - Oscar the Grouch makes "a very brief cameo" in The Great Muppet Caper.
> - Several Sesame Street characters and Uncle Traveling Matt make a cameo appearance at the wedding in The Muppets Take Manhattan.

Comment: Plus, [Rowlf was in the Sesame Street pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rowlf_the_Dog#Career).

Comment: "No" responds correctly to the title question, but the question body flips it around by asking, "Have any other muppets appeared in both franchises?" which gives, "No," quite a different meaning. I dunno if the question should be edited for clarity or if making the meaning of the initial, "No," in this answer more explicit would be better.

Comment: @jpmc26 "Were you at the funeral? No, I had broken my leg earlier that day". Technically, everything after the No is a non sequitur, but you can infer from context that this is the justification for their absence at the funeral. Similarly, Walt continued after the No with providing evidence to the contrary of OP's assumption. Also, a Muppet inherently shows up in "The Muppets". If Walt is talking about "Muppets on Sesame Street", he is inherently talking about "Muppets that show up in both the Muppets and Sesame Street" (and vice versa)

Comment: @Flater You misunderstand. It's more like, "Were you at the funeral? Did you miss it?" "No, my leg was broken." It isn't immediately obvious that the, "No," goes with the first question. As I said, part of the problem is that the post body flips things around by asking the question differently; answering, "No," to, "Have any other muppets actually appeared on both media?" is equivalent to answering, "Yes," to the title question. In such cases where "Yes" or "No" are ambiguous, I typically avoid saying either and just explicitly state what I mean.

Answer (score 18):

A significant portion of the Sesame Street cast can be seen in the ending of Muppets Take Manhattan where Miss Piggy and Kermit get married.  On the groom's side is the Sesame Street cast while the bride's side as the Muppet cast.

Ernie has a speaking (singing) role.  Bert sitting next to him.  Cookie Monster, The Count, Grover, Oscar, Herry, and Big Bird  can be seen the back row. Elmo appears to be on the edge of the scene (0:34 in the above clip). Sully (guy with a hard hat) is sitting next to Bert and Biff (another hard hat next to him).  There is a honker and Mona (blue, small horns), Sherlock (0:38 looking back and 1:25 looking forward).  Harvey monster (large horns, right hand side 1:25), Two Headed monster (left head, 1:26; right head 1:27), Pearl (1:27 - big nose, orange hair) and a grouch (possibly Granny grouch given the hat).

I'm certain that I missed a few minor ones in there.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the answers provided, there's one very specific moment that gets the entire Muppet and Sesame Street team together: A Muppet Family Christmas. To the best of my knowledge, literally every Sesame Street muppet appeared with the regular Muppets.

Comment: This is one of my favorite Christmas shows and my family and I still watch it each Christmas.  I also appreciated that the Fraggles were included in this lot and, IIRC, tucked away in one of the wide shots might have been an otter from Emmet Otter's Jug Band Christmas. As of it's airing, this show had the widest range of Muppet characters.  Times were different and IP for various franchises wasn't as protected.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Wikia page](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Did_Miss_Piggy_appear_on_Sesame_Street%3F), Kermit is the only muppet to appear on Sesame Street, but some Sesame Street characters have appeared on The Muppets.

For example, [episode 318](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_318:_Leslie_Uggams) of The Muppets featured Big Bird.

[image: Big Bird on the Muppets]

https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/muppet/images/3/39/Leslieuggams.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140705154057